# Is there any way to change the apprequests dialog height?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried this:

```
FB.UIServer.Methods["apprequests"].size = {width:600,height:320};
```

The width actually changes but it forces the height to a predefined value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.FB_UI_Dialog {
height: 400px !important;
}
</style>
```

This hack works.